# How do I only add Includes to the EF query when $expand conditions of OData are met

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, ef-core-3.1

**The case**: Since I am using Automapper, I execute the query before OData will do it's filtering. To prevent using more includes than necessary, I want to Include it only when it's present in the `$expand` parameter of OData.
So far I can only find how to filter inside an `.Include()`, but not how to filter on using an `.Include()` at all.

**The problem**: It doesn't include the Addresses.

**The code**:

```cs
var locations = context.Locations;

if (oDataQueryParameters["$expand"].Contains("Addresses"))
{
    locations.Include(l => l.Addresses);
}

locations.Where(l => l.CustomerId == userModel.CustomerId)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**:
I forgot to asign it to locations again. Now my code is like this and it works:

```cs
var locations = context.Locations.AsQueryable();

if (oDataQueryParameters["$expand"].Contains("Addresses"))
{
    locations = locations.Include(l => l.Addresses);
}

locations = locations.Where(l => l.CustomerId == userModel.CustomerId)
    .AsNoTracking();

var locationModels = Mapper.Map<List<LocationModel>>(locations.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was caused by a misconfiguration of the service and the $expand was disabled

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand());
```

Adding `.Expand()` will solve. Now the action:

```
 [EnableQuery]
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult<IEnumerable<SupplierOrder>> GetAll()
 {
     var orders = _ctx.SupplierOrders.AsNoTracking();
     return Ok(orders);
 }
```

The request https://localhost:7021/api/Order will produce

```
  SELECT o."Id", o."Code", o."Discriminator"
  FROM "Orders" AS o
```

and https://localhost:7021/api/Order?$expand=OrderRows will make the join

```
SELECT o."Id", o."Code", o."Discriminator", o0."Id", o0."ArticleId", o0."OrderId", o0."Position", o0."Quantity"
FROM "Orders" AS o
LEFT JOIN "OrderRow" AS o0 ON o."Id" = o0."OrderId"
ORDER BY o."Id"
```

Using .net6 webapp and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.10

Comment: The problem is that this won't work with AutoMapper in between. When using AutoMapper, it will execute the query first and map it to the model. Only after that OData will do its query on the model.

Comment: have you tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore ?